# Oracle listagg - Can I pull data from other table based on the values selected by listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have two tables and want to get data from one table based on the values got from Listtagg in the second table:

```
T1
ID     Name
==============
1      Name1
2      Person2
3      Someone3
4      Mr.4

T2
ID     Acct
===============
1      1234
1      5678
2      1234
3      5678
3      8769
4      1234
```

My listagg query on T2 has returned the following:

```
Acct   Id
====== ========
1234   1,2,4
5678   1,3
```

I need the result with Names from other table something like:

```
Acct   Id       Name
====== ======== ==========
1234   1,2,4    Name1, Person2, Mr.4
5678   1,3      Name1, Someone3
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you first aggregate `ID`s, and then put effort in splitting them to collect `NAME`s? Do it immediately. Not that it can't be done (it can, in a relatively simple manner, but - why?!?).

Sample data is from line #1 - 15; query you might need begins at line #16.

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (id, name) as
  3    (select 1, 'Name1' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Person2' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Someone3' from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'Mr4' from dual
  7    ),
  8  t2 (id, acct) as
  9    (select 1, 1234 from dual union all
 10     select 1, 5678 from dual union all
 11     select 2, 1234 from dual union all
 12     select 3, 5678 from dual union all
 13     select 3, 8769 from dual union all
 14     select 4, 1234 from dual
 15    )
 16  select b.acct,
 17    listagg(b.id, ', ') within group (order by b.id) id,
 18    listagg(a.name, ', ') within group (order by b.id) name
 19  from t1 a join t2 b on a.id = b.id
 20  group by b.acct;

      ACCT ID         NAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
      1234 1, 2, 4    Name1, Person2, Mr4
      5678 1, 3       Name1, Someone3
      8769 3          Someone3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot's answer is absolutely correct. But just as an addition: don't use listagg if you are going to split those aggregated values. Just use `collect()` aggregate function to get needed data as a collection.
For example:

```sql
select 
   cast(collect(level) as sys.odcinumberlist) as varray_of_numbers,
   cast(collect(level) as ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT) as nested_table_of_numbers,
   cast(collect(sys.ku$_objnum(level)) as sys.KU$_OBJNUMSET) as nested_table_of_objnum
from dual connect by level<=3;

--Result:
VARRAY_OF_NUMBERS         NESTED_TABLE_OF_NUMBERS        NESTED_TABLE_OF_OBJNUM(OBJ_NUM)
------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3)   ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT(1, 2, 3)  KU$_OBJNUMSET(KU$_OBJNUM(1), KU$_OBJNUM(2), KU$_OBJNUM(3))
```

**Update**: This is a query for your tables, as you asked in the comment:

```sql
select b.acct,
  cast(collect(b.id) as ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT) as nested_table_of_numbers,
  cast(collect(a.name) as ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT) as nested_table_of_varchar2
--  listagg(b.id, ', ') within group (order by b.id) id,
--  listagg(a.name, ', ') within group (order by b.id) name
from t1 a join t2 b on a.id = b.id
group by b.acct;
```

Full example:

```sql
with
t1 (id, name) as
  (select 1, 'Name1' from dual union all
   select 2, 'Person2' from dual union all
   select 3, 'Someone3' from dual union all
   select 4, 'Mr4' from dual
  ),
t2 (id, acct) as
  (select 1, 1234 from dual union all
   select 1, 5678 from dual union all
   select 2, 1234 from dual union all
   select 3, 5678 from dual union all
   select 3, 8769 from dual union all
   select 4, 1234 from dual
  )
select b.acct,
  cast(collect(b.id) as ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT) as nested_table_of_numbers,
  cast(collect(a.name) as ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT) as nested_table_of_varchar2
--  listagg(b.id, ', ') within group (order by b.id) id,
--  listagg(a.name, ', ') within group (order by b.id) name
from t1 a join t2 b on a.id = b.id
group by b.acct;
```

Comment: Can you please include fields from the tables I showed above, so that it is easy for me try.